# Wordpress search posts by author name with autocomplete

Tags: wp-query, wp-user-query

I am using autocomplete code as follows:

**functions.php**

```
// add the ajax fetch js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });
}
</script>
<?php }

// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

 $the_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
        'post_type' => 'post',

        ),
    );

    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        ?><ul><?php
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

        $myquery = esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] );
        $a = $myquery;
        $search = get_the_title();
        if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) {?>
            <li><a class="articles-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a> by <?php the_author(); ?></li>
        <?php }
    endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?></ul><?php
    endif;
    die();
}
```

**Page template.php**

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()"></input>
<div id="datafetch">Search results will appear here</div>
```

This works great for autocomplete searching of posts, but I am having great difficulty allowing it to search by author name (with role->author) instead of, or as well as post title.

I have tried to use a WP_User_Query in place of the WP_Query like so:

```
$args = array (
    'role'           => 'author',
    's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<li><span>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</span></li>';
    }
}
    die();
}
```

This just brings up the list of every author.  Is there a way to run a WP_User_Query with a `while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();` instead of a `foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {`?  Or is there some other way to allow the search to bring up an autocompleted list of posts by way of a username search?  I can't figure out how.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WP_User_Query uses the parameter `search` rather than `s`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/#search-parameters

So try this instead

```
$args = array (
    'role'           => 'author',
    'search' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
);
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you(!), that works, BUT only when I put in the full username.  Do you know of a way to match partial searches?

Comment: Figured it out, for anyone who comes here wondering, add asterisks to the WP_user_query arguments, like so:`'search' => '*'.esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ).'*',`

Also, Howard, I'm sorry I can't upvote your answer as I don't have enough rep points, but thank you so much for your help.